# It is possible to use regression to measure the correlation between a continuous variable and a dummy variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, linear-model, categorical-encoding

I have 3 columns: one column is a continuous variable (e.g., age) and the other two columns represent dummy variables with values 1 and 0 (yes/no).

What kind of regression do I have to use to measure the correlation between age and the other binary variables?

I tried linear regression but it does not seem to work properly.

Comment: Do you have two dummy variables or one?

Comment: Two dummy variable and Age

Comment: Do you want to know the correlation between age and each dummy variable? Or are you trying to use age and the other two binary inputs to predict some target variable? Please provide a little more clarification.

Comment: Only the correlation

Comment: I think your data is perfectly fine to be handled by a linear model

Comment: I used age as dipendent variables and dummies as indipendent, but i thinks the model is not correct. R2 is really low

Comment: A low R^2 only means that your variables do not explain much of the variation in your y variable, age. That could be because of model misspecification.

Comment: I want to explain this. My dataset is obteneid from a survey question that is :'how do you find out about this survey?' so i have my variables age and my 2 dummies variable Facebook(1=yes,0=no) and same for instagram(yes/no) . I want to explain that lower is the age, greater is the probability that peoples finded out the survey with this social network.

Comment: You may want to consider calculating a point biserial correlation coefficient. Python's `SciPy` library may help: `stats.pointbiserialr(x, y)`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Tomorrow i will try point biserial correlation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Cross Validated! There is no problem between mixing covariates that are discrete and continuous in a regression. Based on your question it sounds an issue may have come up in the implementation. If you are doing this in R make sure to make your discrete covariates factors (For other languages you will need to check the proper categorical-encoding). For example,

```
X1 <- rbinom(100,1,0.71)
X2 <- rnorm(100)

Y = 2*X1 + 3*X2 + rnorm(100)

lm(Y ~ factor(X1) + X2)
```

With output:

````
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ factor(X1) + X2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  factor(X1)1           X2  
   -0.08094      2.11226      2.85840  

```
````

Comment: I use python but i understand R languange. I dont understand what 0.71 is in rbinom. And why you make 2*x1 + 3*x2

Comment: This is simply an example to demonstrate that you may use both discrete and continuous covariates. 0.71 is the Bernoulli-p which generates a 0-1 random variable.

Comment: Ok thanks! And why 2*x1 + 3*x2

Comment: This is just how I choose to define the outcome variable in the example above. I could have made it anything. All this is doing is illustrating that the linear regression is perfectly applicable to the case you described with discrete and continuous independent variables.